# Unable to execute selenium java program using both chrome and gecko driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am planning to automate browser using selenium using java and eclipse, but when am trying to execute the program its giving me exception " Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.session.CapabilitiesFilter: module org.openqa.selenium.remote does not declare `uses`"

Below was the code which am trying to execute.

```
package com.sample;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
//comment the above line and uncomment below line to use Chrome
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class Myclass {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Automation\\geckodriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //comment the above 2 lines and uncomment below 2 lines to use Chrome
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


        /*
         * System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
         * "D:\\Automation\\geckodriver.exe"); DesiredCapabilities capabilities =
         * DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); capabilities.setCapability("marionette",true);
         * WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
         */     
        String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
        String actualTitle = "";

        // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        // get the actual value of the title
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        /*
         * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
         * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
         */
        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }

        //close Fire fox
        driver.close();

    }

}
```

Tried using both chromedriver and geckodriver, but both were having same problem. Please help.

Comment: what error are you facing ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.session.CapabilitiesFilter: module org.openqa.selenium.remote does not declare `uses`
 at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:590)

Comment: issue already reported here please check [github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7676)

Comment: Now am getting this issue. Below are the prints from eclipse. "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules selenium.support and okio export package org.openqa.selenium.support.events.internal to module error.prone.annotations"

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ResolutionException, you must need to include selenium jar because your IDE is failed to detect it. if its present then try to remove external jars from your end.

Once you done that, try to restart your IDEas well.